# Entity Framework not able to add data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm doing a project where I have to use EF, but trying to add new data to the table seems to fail every time. I have no knowledge to why/how I can fix it.

The code executing is:

```
private static void AddCustomer()
{
        WriteAdminMenu("Add new customer");
        Console.Write("First name: ");
        ...
        WriteAdminMenu("Adding customer...");

        using (var db = new EshopContext())
        {
            db.Addresses.Add(new Address(customerStreet, customerZip, customerCity, customerCountry));
        }
    }
```

And I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Address'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'zip' in 'Address(string street, string zip, string city, string country)'

Context file:

```
public class EshopContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer>? Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address>? Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order>? Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product>? Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag>? Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
       => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=TotallyMyIp;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=TotalyMyUserName;Password=totallySecretPassword");
}
```

And my address model:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public Address(string street, string zip, string city, string country)
    {
        Street = street;
        Zipcode = zip;
        City = city;
        Country = country;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework has no way to know that `zip` is the same as `Zipcode`.

Keep your names consistent:

```
public Address(string street, string zipcode, string city, string country)
```

Comment: Don't "Zipcode = zip" bypass that?

Now having done that i get another not suitable. I don't know if its best to comment, edit question or make a new question for this error

Comment: @BaconBotMK1: No, `Zipcode = zip` does nothing to change the signature of the constructor.  Just look carefully at what the error is telling you.  It *was* able to figure out the other three constructor parameters, the only one it couldn't figure out was `zip`.  Which is the only one that doesn't match any properties on the object.

Comment: @BaconBotMK1: How to proceed with the new error depends on what that error is.  If it's unrelated then a new question would likely be in order.

Comment: It's still in the "no suitable constructor" but for another class.

Comment: @BaconBotMK1: If it's the same problem for the same reason then it's likely the same solution.

Comment: This time it's the same naming in the property and in the parameter. Both having a class as data type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248784/discussion-between-baconbotmk1-and-david).